# Get all runes with id and name from League of legends API

Tags: riot-games-api

When performing requests to the riot API endpoint [/lol/match/v4/matches/{matchId}](https://developer.riotgames.com/apis#match-v4) the response contains rune data for each player in the match .e.g

```
"perk0": 8005,
"perk0Var1": 2107,
"perk0Var2": 1319,
"perk0Var3": 788,
```

These are only the Id values for the runes. Where can I get the corresponding name for the rune ?

I've tried the following request : https://euw1.api.riotgames.com/lol/static-data/v1/runes , but returns the following response :

```
{
    "status": {
        "message": "Forbidden",
        "status_code": 403
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the resource that stores all the needed data here : http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.16.1/data/en_US/runesReforged.json

Comment: Note: if you want to have new runes, change the version (10.16.1) in the URL to something newer (e.g., 14.2.1 at the time of writing).  Data Dragon is really useful to gather item, rune, champion data https://riot-api-libraries.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ddragon.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to quickly fetch and create a rune ID: name dictionary from Data Dragon (including the 5 "perks"):

```python
import requests

def ddragon_get_runes_dict(version="14.2.1"):
    url = f"http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/{version}/data/en_US/runesReforged.json"
    html = requests.get(url).json()
    perk_dict = {item["id"]: item["key"] for item in html} #Domination (8100), Inspiration (8300), Precision (8000), Resolve (8400), Sorcery (8200)
    rune_dict = {rune["id"]: rune["key"] for item in html for slot in item["slots"] for rune in slot["runes"]}
    return perk_dict | rune_dict
```

Don't forget to change the version!